# Meaning of "do over"

Tags: slang

A colleague and I are having a disagreement over the **slang** meaning and usage of **"do over"**

Does it mean

(a) beat somebody up

or does it have a sexual meaning of

(b) screw someone i.e. hump someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BE it means "to beat up" as Ham&Bacon said - but in AE 'a do over' is a chance to do something again if you make a mistake and have the previous attempt not count or be recorded.

eg in golf, if you completely spoil a shot then you might get "a do-over", a chance to have it not count but take the shot again. For some odd reason it's also called a [mulligan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulligan_%28games%29)

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, it [means :](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_over)

> (UK, slang) To beat up.

The word which has the sexual connotation is just "do", not "do over":

> Slang meaning "to do the sex act with or to" is from 1913.

The answer to your question is, they mean different things.

Comment: I was happy until I realized your 2nd link explains the slang meaning of **do** and not *do over*

Comment: Hang on, edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Originally a Kiwi (New Zealand) term from the 1860s, "do over" means to assault or beat up, and has been part of aussie slang since the 1940s.